# How to run test before merge a pullrequest

Tags: git, pull-request

I'm using GIT with pull-request workflow (https://www.atlassian.com/git/workflows#!pull-request).

Usually all the developers run alls the test before creating a pull request, but i want to be sure that a pull request doesn't break the build.

How can I run all my test **before** merging a pull request?

Comment: I know this is an old question. If you want to automatize the process maybe have a look at CI tests feature on Github https://developer.github.com/apps/quickstart-guides/creating-ci-tests-with-the-checks-api/

Comment: Thanks, times goes by and now I'm using jenkins + github webhook for all the automation.

Answer (score 4):

```
# Create a temporary branch in your local repository.
git checkout -b temp-branch
# Merge the remote branch that contains the pull request.
git pull git://foo.com/repo.git feature-branch
# Run tests.
make test
# Go back to the previous branch.
git checkout -
# Delete the temporary branch.
git branch -D temp-branch
```

If the tests passed, merge the pull request into the actual target branch.

Another way to do it is to have a staging branch that exists only for testing purposes.  Once tests pass in that branch, commits can move on to master.  This way is probably easier to automate.

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps by running `git merge --no-commit`, then running the test, and then either `git commit` or `git reset --hard HEAD` depending on the outcome of the test?